# How do you find the closest point to line on a geometric network in VBA?

Tags: math, vba

I work in GIS with VBA.  I have a geometric network that contains 2 layer River (polyline) and Hydrometry station (Point).  I want to find the closest Point to the selected River, but I want that distance to be measured on the network, not the direct distance.

How can I code this in VBA?

Comment: This is better suited for gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer your question because you don't describe your "geometric network" in any detail, but the [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) will find all distances in the network between points on the river and points at hydrometry stations.

Wikipedia has [links to implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Implementations) in many languages; there should be no difficulty in adapting one to VBA.